# Linear Combinations of Random Variable - Variance Difference

Tags: statistics, random-variables, variance

So i was doing this question and I'm a bit confused at the working on the back:

Q. The lengths of red pencils are normally distributed with mean 6.5 cm and standard deviation 0.23 cm.
(i) Two red pencils are chosen at random. Find the probability that their total length is greater than 12.5 cm.

The lengths of black pencils are normally distributed with mean 11.3 cm and standard deviation 0.46 cm.
(ii) Find the probability that the total length of 3 red pencils is more than 6.7 cm greater than the length of 1 black pencil.

So for part ii) I took it as 3R - B > 6.7

and according to this the mean would be 3(6.5) - 11.3 so thats 6.7 and i took variance as 3^2(0.23)^2 + (0.46)^2 which comes as 0.6877 but the answer at the back took variance for red pencils as 3 x (0.23) ^2. why is that so?????? i mean it makes sense in part i to take 2 x (0.23)^2 but i dont think that should be the case for ii or am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you think the rule to use for part $ii$ is not the same as for part $i$ ?  It is the same situation: calculating the mean and variance for the sum of independent normally distributed random variables.  Just ... one involves two variables, the other four.

Comment: Ah, that is because at times we're given a question such as find P( 3X - Y < 20) and we do different working than part (i) so I thought maybe that would be the case with this question too. Do you perhaps know how can I differentiate between which method to use?

Comment: It is just: "the length of 3 red pencils" ($\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 R_i)$ versus "3 times the length of *a* red pencil" $(3R)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *not* multiplying the value of the one random variable, $R$, by three, rather you *are* summing three independent random variables *each* with an *identical distribution* to $R$.

The variance of a sum of normal distributed random variables equals the sum of the variances of the variables.

Also $\mathsf{Var}(-B)=\mathsf {Var}(B)$ so the *variance of the difference* of two ND random variables equals the *addition of their variances*.

Thusly:

$$\mathsf {Var}(R_1+R_2+R_3-B)=3\,\mathsf{Var}(R)+\mathsf{Var}(B)$$

Comment: Thank you very much!